# Coding distributions in RStan

Tags: distribution, stan

I am very new in RStan and I am having problems coding in it. My research is about fitting a nonparametric regression function to data using cubic smoothing splines. I did most of the R code but now I am having issues with the Stan part.

This is the part I am stuck on

[image: This is the part I am stuck on]

I already found Q and Z in R but I don't know how to write all those distributions in Stan. I would appreciate any help! Thank you.